# SVN on a subdomain, can't authorize user's from .htpassword on apache/plesk/setup

Tags: linux, svn, apache, subdomain

I've setup a repo on my server that i access through a sub domain "svn.site.com"

My vhost.conf has

```
#/var/www/vhosts/isuckatwebdesign.com/subdomains/svn/conf/vhost.conf
ServerName svn.isuckatwebdesign.com
<Location />
#svn.isuckatwebdesign.com -- vhost.conf file

DAV svn
SVNPath /var/www/vhosts/isuckatwebdesign.com/subdomains/svn/svnrepo/isuk
#AuthType Basic
#AuthName "Subversion Repository"
#AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
#Require valid-user
</Location>
```

When I comment out the Authorization like i have in the code block I don't get a 500 internal server error when logging into the repo and it displays the repo but I can't commit to the repo, if it's uncommented it gives the server error.

Apache Error log displays

```
    [Sun Apr 10 07:38:55 2011] [crit] [client 214.27.58.2] configuration error:  couldn't check access.  No groups file?: /
    [Sun Apr 10 07:38:55 2011] [crit] [client 214.27.58.2] configuration error:  couldn't check access.  No groups file?: /error_docs/internal_server_error.html
```

Answer (score 0):

In subversion you can define groups of users and grant privileges to those groups based on their authentication. Thus, if your subversion repository has groups defined, and since you are not providing any authentication at all SVN cannot link your user to any group and you may have been defaulted to a read-only group.

Can you double check the SVN groups defined in your repository?

I cannot be entirely sure, but the book tells about this configuration possibilities
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth

I configured a repo months ago and I use Apache authentication and SVN groups.

Comment: If I'm using htaccess or htpasswd I thought i didn't need to assign groups? that does explain why i cant commit when not using authorization, If i turn on authorization I can't even read the repo though, it doesn't seem to be authenticating properly or something.

How do I actually list the svn groups for a repo? or add a group?

Comment: Check the /conf folder in the repo. You will find what you are looking for there.

Comment: I believe that would only be in the situation that i use SVNSERV instead of Apache for authentication.

I figured out what the issue was though. I wasn't loading the Mod_authz_user.so module in apache. LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so